# Popup with GridView that covers part of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

**UPDATE:** I figured it out. See my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65826225/396949)

I am presenting a `GridView` as a popup route that produces

[image]

with the code below

```
class GridPopup extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Close popup'),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              // Expanded(
              //   child: GridView.count(
              GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 5,
                crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: List.generate(
                  25,
                  (index) => Container(color: Colors.green),
                ),
              ),
              // ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code available here: [gist](https://gist.github.com/mrvincenzo/0d99c3134bee60c79386fcb376dad100) [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/0d99c3134bee60c79386fcb376dad100)

The problem is that when the number of items in the `GridView` increases, it overflows

[image]

It can be fixed by wrapping `GridView` with `Expanded` but then, the popup always covers the whole screen

[image]

Can I fix the overflow without using the `Expanded` widget and without specifying sizes? In other words, I want the popup's height to be the smallest possible (less when there are few items, more when there are many items) while still containing the GridView so it won't overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The `GridView` should be wrapped with `Flexible` widget instead of `Expanded`. The rest of the code remains unchanged.

```
...
Flexible(
  child: GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 5,
    crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: List.generate(
      25,
      (index) => Container(color: Colors.green),
    ),
  ),
),
...
```

Updated [gist](https://gist.github.com/mrvincenzo/2fa5d82033eafc3e37c54be5c4a67113) and [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/2fa5d82033eafc3e37c54be5c4a67113)

Answer (score 1):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]You need to provide the scrollDirection feature and you need to make shrinkWrap false. and you need to cover half of us.

```
class GridPopup extends StatelessWidget {
int countContainer = 35;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
double heightPopup = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
            (((countContainer / 5).toDouble()) / 10) >
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
    ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
    : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
        ((((countContainer / 5) + 1) / 10));

print(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height.toString());
print("heightPopup" + heightPopup.toString());
return SafeArea(
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: Container(
      height: heightPopup,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Close popup'),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
            ),
          ),

          Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 5,
              crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
              childAspectRatio: 1.0,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              children: List.generate(
                countContainer,
                (index) => Container(color: Colors.green),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
   ),
 );
}
}
```

Comment: I don't want the popup to be limited in size. I can fix my issue by limiting it to a specific size without changing `shrinkWrap` and without using `scrollDirection`

Comment: You can not. but you can do it like this. I'm updating the answer. This is the most logical one as you want. in my opinion

Comment: Actually, you can. One should use `Flexible` instead of `Expanded`. I've answered my own question - check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65826225/396949). I also included a dart pad that visualizes the differences

Answer (score -1):

change GripPop to, remove mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min and shrinkWrap: true:

```
  void _presentGridPopup(BuildContext context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (context) {
          return FractionallySizedBox(
            heightFactor: 0.8,
            child: GridPopup(),
          );
        });
  }

    class GridPopup extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Close popup'),
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 5,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                      children: List.generate(
                        100,
                        (index) => Container(color: Colors.green),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Nope. Getting `A RenderFlex overflowed by 982 pixels on the bottom.` The idea behind the `shrinkWrap: true` and `MainAxisSize.min` is to present a popup that doesn't cover the whole screen...

Comment: then you should use showModalBottomSheet in this case better, updated answer

Comment: Not quite. `showModalBottomSheet` covers a fixed portion of the screen. I want the popup height to change according to its content. You can check your suggestions in this [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/0d99c3134bee60c79386fcb376dad100)